# Adding class in parent <li> if it's the current location with Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, coffeescript

I've tried to use this code but it returns 'undefined'.

```
(($) -> 
    $('li.menu-item a').each (index, element) ->
        if $(element).attr('href') == $(location).attr('href')
            $(element).parent().addClass('selected');
) jQuery
```

Here follows my HTML code:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why not just use an attribute selector to get the correct element, e.g. `$("li.menu-item a[href='" + location.href + "']").parent().addClass('selected')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your `bloginfo('url')` PHP function call returns just the path component of the URL (i.e. something `'/some/path'` with the scheme, port, or hostname). Why would that be a problem? Well, [`location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) is:

> [...] a DOMString containing the whole URL.

So `location.href` will contain the schema, hostname, port, ... and the comparison with just the pathname will always fail. I suspect that you just want to look at `location.pathname`:

```
$('li.menu-item a').each (index, element) ->
    if $(element).attr('href') == location.pathname
        $(element).parent().addClass('selected');
```

Also, there's no need to wrap `location` in jQuery so I switch to just `location.pathname`.

Even better, combine that with [Jordan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan) comment and say:

```
$("li.menu-item a[href='#{location.pathname}']").parent().addClass('selected')
```